# Vertical Line ggplot for x categorical variable (not date)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe that I'm trying to make a vertical line on an x-axis that is categorical.

```
data <- data.frame(
  condition = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'),
  AssessmentGrade = c('400', '410', '420', '430', '440', '500', '510', '520', '530', '540', 
                      '300', '310', '320', '330', '340'), 
  Freq = c('1', '2', '1', '5', '7', '9', '1', '5', '3', '4', '5', '8', '1', '3', '5'), 
  MathGrade = c('A+', 'B-', 'C-', 'D', 'F', 'A-', 'B', 'C+', 'D-', 'F', 'A+', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'C'), 
  Condition = c('Condition 1', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 1', 
                'Condition 2', 'Condition 2', 'Condition 2', 'Condition 2', 'Condition 2', 
                'Condition 3', 'Condition 3', 'Condition 3', 'Condition 3', 'Condition 3'))
```

I tried adding a field to make grade numeric and that helped

```
data$Gradenum <- as.numeric(data$MathGrade)
```

I used ggplot to get abubble graph but I was wondering how I would edit it to use my company's standard colors

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = MathGrade, y = AssessmentGrade, size = Freq, fill = Condition)) +
 geom_point(aes(colour = Condition)) +
 ggtitle("Main Title") +
 labs(x = "First Math Grade", y = "Math Assessment Score")
```

How can I get a vertical line between C+ and D? I see a lot of information out there if your x axis is a date but not for other categorical values

Comment: @Miha IMHO, that's not a good dupe target as the linked question was asking for a vertical line at an x-position where the continuous data has a certain y-value. Here, the OP is asking to draw a vertical line for a categorial variable.

Comment: @Walker Is it intended that the grades are ordered A-, A+, B, B-, C, C-, C+, ...? Shouldn't it read A+, A-, B, B-, C+, C, C-, ... instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `geom_vline` ;)

```
p + geom_vline(xintercept = 7.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Can we say "holy over thinking batman" to me? thank you! once i made the numeric i thought i had to specifically say data$Gradenum=7.5 and i didn't know how to call that. so easy! thank you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

#### Hardcoded solutions are error-prone

[MrSnake's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376577/3817004) works - but only for the given data set because the value of 7.5 is *hardcoded*.

It will fail with just a minor change to the data, e.g., by replacing grade `"A+"` in row 1 of `data` by an `"A"`.

Using the hardcoded `xintercept` of 7.5

```
p + geom_vline(xintercept = 7.5)
```

draws the line between  grades *C-* and *C+* instead of *C+* and *D*:

[image]

This can be solved using *ordered factors*. But first note that the chart contains another flaw: The grades on the x-axis are ordered *alphabetically*

> A, A-, A+, B, B-, C, C-, C+, D, D-, F

where I would have expected

> A+, A, A-, B, B-, C+, C, C-, D, D-, F

#### Fixing the x-axis

This can be fixed by turning `MathGrade` into an ordered factor with levels in a given order:

```
grades <- c(as.vector(t(outer(LETTERS[1:4], c("+", "", "-"), paste0))), "F")
grades
```

> ```
>  [1] "A+" "A"  "A-" "B+" "B"  "B-" "C+" "C"  "C-" "D+" "D"  "D-" "F"
> ```

```
data$MathGrade <- ordered(data$MathGrade, levels = grades)
```

`factor()`would be sufficient to plot a properly ordered x-axis but we need an ordered factor for the next step, the correct placement of the vertical line.

#### Programmatically placing the vertical line

Let's suppose that the vertical line should be drawn between grades *C-* and *D+*. However, it may happen that either or both grades are missing from the data. Missing factors won't be plotted. In the sample data set, there are no data with grade *D+*, so the vertical line should be plotted between grades *C-* and *D*.

So, we need to look for the lowest grade equal or greater *D+* and the highest grade equal or less than *C-* in the data set:

```
upper <- as.character(min(data$MathGrade[data$MathGrade >= "D+"]))
lower <- as.character(max(data$MathGrade[data$MathGrade <= "C-"]))
```

These are the grades in the actual data set where the vertical line is to be plotted between:

```
xintercpt <- mean(which(levels(droplevels(data$MathGrade)) %in% c(lower, upper)))
p + geom_vline(xintercept = xintercpt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For changing the colors as to fit your company scheme, you can add something like:

```
  + scale_color_manual(values = c('Condition 1' = 'grey20', 
                                'Condition 2' = 'darkred', 
                                'Condition 3' = 'blue'))
```