# Adjust yend in geom_segment when x is categorical

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-segment

I would like to adjust the vertical position of the `geom_segment` when x is categorical. In the example below the `geom_segment` is centered around the variable on the x-axis.

I would like draw the segment starting on the line of the x-axis variable and extending towards above. I tried something like `yend = variable + 1` which obvisouly does not work.

The question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376493/vertical-line-ggplot-for-x-categorical-variable-not-date) regarding `geom_vline` with categorical axis. However, I think something like `yintercept = ...` would not work in my case.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata = data.frame(variable = factor(c("A","A","A","B","C")),
                    color = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                    start = c(1,2,1,4,6),
                    end = c(3,4,6,5,8))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = start, xend = end, y = variable, yend = variable)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(color = color), size = 10)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The reason I ask is because in my real data I add a histogram to each x-variable (with `ggridges::geom_density_ridges`) which starts on the line of the x-axis variable. The plot looks strange if `geom_segment` and `geom_density_ridges` do not lie on the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `geom_rect` instead.

```r
library(ggplot2)
mydata = data.frame(variable = factor(c("A","A","A","B","C")),
                    color = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                    start = c(1,2,1,4,6),
                    end = c(3,4,6,5,8))

ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, 
                ymin = variable, ymax = as.numeric(variable) + 0.2, 
                fill = color))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>